# how to spawn boxes side by side

Tags: html, css

Hello i am trying to spawn boxes side by side i dont know what to do i have tried
using `Float:left;` but that also didnt work 
here is my css code

```
    <style>
div.heh
{
width:550px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid black;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: .5px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  min-height: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
box-align:left
float:left;
}
div.hehh
{
width:550px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid black;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: .5px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  min-height: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
box-align:right
float:right;
}

</style>
<!------- here is the HTML Structure ----->
  <div class="heh" align="left">
        <h3>SteamRep:<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  >Normal</button><br>
        <a href="http://backpack.tf/id/712">View Backpack</a><br>
        <a href="http://www.tf2outpost.com/user/285419">View TF2Outpost</a>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="hehh">
      <h3>Positive Reputation:<font color="green">100</font><br>
      Negative Reputation:<font color="red">1</font></br>
      Total Raffles Participated:<font color="green">12</font><br>
      Warnings Received:<font color="red">0</font><br>      

      </h3>    
      </div>
```

In the above code the boxes would spawn below each other i dont know what is going wrong i have searched elsewhere also didnt find much resources here is the image[image: thats the image]

Comment: you forgot to add a ';' after 'box-align:left' under 'div.heh'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Css method will also help you to make responsive Web site and reduce code redundancy in css.

Html

```
<div class="heh" align="left">
    <h3>SteamRep:<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  >Normal</button><br>
        <a href="http://backpack.tf/id/712">View Backpack</a><br>
        <a href="http://www.tf2outpost.com/user/285419">View TF2Outpost</a>
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="heh last">
    <h3>Positive Reputation:<font color="green">100</font><br>
        Negative Reputation:<font color="red">1</font></br>
        Total Raffles Participated:<font color="green">12</font><br>
        Warnings Received:<font color="red">0</font><br>      
    </h3>    
</div>
```

Css

```
div.heh
{
    float:left;
    width:42%;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 5px solid #e3e3e3;
    border-radius: 1px;
    padding: 19px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    min-height: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
        box-align:left
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}
.heh.last{margin:0 !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

`float:left;` is the way to go, but I assume they don't fit next to each other in their parent container. Consequently, they *want* to be next to each other, but since that is impossible, they will display beneath each other.

So you need to make the parent container wider, or the child divs smaller.

Comment: well how do i do that

Comment: Use a width:300px; for instance and see what happens.

Comment: The box-align property has no trailing ; which causes other problems. See comment on original post.

Answer (score 0):

reduce the width for both div and use width:200px; 
it will be working

Answer (score -1):

Just add `display:inline-block` to two div css classes
Each div size is 550px so if screen size is above 1100px only display side by side

**CSS**

```
div.heh
{
width:550px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid black;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: .5px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  min-height: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
box-align:left;
float:left;
    display:inline-block
}
div.hehh
{
width:550px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid black;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: .5px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  min-height: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
box-align:right;
float:right;
    display:inline-block
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RLZd8/3/)

Comment: You fixed the box-align: right; with a semicolon, which I assume did the trick (as others noted). The display inline-block is not necessary and makes your component into an inline element, which probably is not what you want...